# How can I mark an answer as a community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

A comment to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180539/27377) mentions "community wiki":

> You could always self answer and mark as a community wiki so people can just expand on it as more are found

Being a member for (almost) 5 years I've never used such a feature. How can I mark an answer as a community wiki and what effect does it cause?

A related question — [How should we use Community Wiki, Part III](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/) (but it assumes the reader already knows what a community wiki is, and it doesn't explain the technical part "how do I mark an answer for it")

Comment: From main meta FAQ: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What community wiki posts are is explained in the [Help Center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):

> #### What are Community Wiki posts?
>
> Community wiki posts are more easily editable by all users, and do not confer any reputation.

When you edit your answer, there's a checkbox underneath:

[image]

You'll get a popup for confirmation, and the community wiki status is only applied after you submit the edit anyway.

Comment: More easily specifically means 100 rep, which is where the [edit community wiki privilege](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) is earned. There's also the symbolic part that it is less associated with the specific author, but that's not necessarily beneficial.